# Receiving errors when trying to draw with UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, ios4

I'm trying to draw some lines inside my custom UIView.

From what I can see, to save messing around with CoreGraphics, I can use UIBezierPath (i've done similar with NSBezierPath on the Mac).
I have some code that tries to draw the lines but I get output errors and can't find a decent reference with some sample code to illustrate whats going on, any ideas?
Code below...

Code:

```
  - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    UIBezierPath *line1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
 [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
 [line1 setLineWidth:3];
 [line1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
 [line1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(320, 480)];
 [line1 stroke];

}
```

Errors:

```
Sat Oct  2 19:26:43 mercury.config mobileManual[46994] <Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
```

UPDATE: Here's the current code, No errors but also no drawing.. ideas?

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    UIBezierPath *line1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [line1 setLineWidth:3];
    [line1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [line1 addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(320, 480)];
    [line1 stroke];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: I just tried your updated code and it worked like a charm. Just to be clear, drawRect: is on your UIView subclass and viewDidLoad is on your UIViewController subclass, correct?

Comment: LOL yes it is, but only once I realised I had to subclass UIView and override drawRect in that. Now all good. Thanks for pointing the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said above, your code is working fine for me.

Are you changing the "Class Identity" of the view in Interface Builder to your UIView subclass?

(As an aside, calling setNeedsDisplay in viewDidLoad is unnecessary, but it's also not hurting anything.)

Comment: It's very surprising that the _Class Identity_ was the problem. If it's not correctly set, _drawRect:_ isn't called at all. But there were a lot of error messages from the function (see the original question).

Answer (score 1):

Your graphics context is invalid. This happens because:

- You called *drawRect:* yourself. Never do that. Call *setNeedsDisplay* instead and have iOS call it.
- You somehow destroyed the current graphics context (less likely).

Comment: ah that is making sense. Thank you. What is the syntax for UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ?

Comment: See updated code in the question above, any thoughts as to where I am not handling this correctly? I have no errors but no drawing either.

Comment: -1. You don't need to call UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); -[UIColor setStroke] does that for you.